# Trying to install xgboost in python on windows

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, installation, xgboost

I have been driving myself crazy trying to install xgboost in python on windows 10. I have looked through several suggested articles but still can't seem to find a proper solution. If anyone has done this before kindly share your method other suggestions are also welcome.

Thank

Comment: Did you follow this article specifically?
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md#building-on-windows

Comment: I tried following it, downloaded git for windows, tried creating a buildbut it keep throwing error like - 
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'xgboost': Permission denied
The steps are not very clear and I have not used GIT before thats why I am having a hard time doing this....

Comment: Open MinGW as administrator and try again. That should handle `permission denied` errors.

Comment: Hey I am getting this error

      `cp: cannot stat 'make/mingw64.mk': No such file or directory
bash: mingw32-make: command not found`

Even after adding this statement in the .bashhrc
`alias make='mingw32-make'`

Comment: That just means you're in the wrong directory. In general, when you are using command line environments such as MinGW and even the Windows cmd, you use the `cd` command to move directories (`cd` is an abbreviation for `change directory`).

Did you add `alias make='mingw32-make'` to the `.bashrc` file?
If you did, do the following: `source ~/.bashrc`
What's the output of `pwd` in MinGW?

Comment: I can try to help you through it if you want. Join this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108311/room-for-headless-0ne-and-uasthana

Comment: Yes I added that command in
`C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc` file
Am I suppose to run `source ~/.bashrc` in bash prompt because it s giving me an error
`bash: source~/.bashrc: No such file or directory`
You are right to say I am not in the right directory, which directory should I be in to run this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108312/discussion-between-headless-0ne-and-uasthana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and just got it resolved! So, basically it's because the "openmp" component is not installed since it's not selected as default. Do the following and it'll work for you!

1. Close Git Bash
2. Uninstall TDM-GCC
3. Reinstall TDM-GCC and be sure to select openmp
4. try again using Git Bash
5. If still doesn't work, start from beginning the whole process [as described in this page](https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/)

Also refer to [this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872334/4896087).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install xgboost on Win and Python using Visual Studio following [these instructions](http://www.thushv.com/uncategorized/i-knew-you-were-trouble-xgboost-windows-a-proper-guide/#comment-60).