# compling with mingw32 to install xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost, tdm-mingw, tdm-gcc

Ok so I am installing xgboost using the answer found in this link:-
[How can I install XGBoost package in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510582/how-can-i-install-xgboost-package-in-python)
Now I have followed the steps till installing TDM-GCC when I try the command:-

```
alias make='mingw32-make'
```

I get the following the error message :

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64> alias make='mingw32-make'
alias : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'make=mingw32-make' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ alias make='mingw32-make'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make=mingw32-make:String) [Get-Alias], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand
```

Please help. Also I have tried running it in the xgboost folder and it is still gives the same error message.Also I have installed the 64-bit version of TDM-GCC.